# what circuit the following verilog code produce

Tags: verilog

I was learning Verilog. I was posed by the following code and asked what the following code realize i.e., the circuit implemented.

```
always@(posedge clk or posedge reset or posedge set)
begin 
   if(reset)
      out=in1;
   else if(set)
      out=in2;
    else
     out=d;
end
```

Edit: Here it may have a single D flipflop with reset and set if in1=0, in2 =1. But I don't understand how three inputs? May be Mux comes into picture 
Can someone help me

Comment: It isn't synthesizable; therefore, it will produce no circuit at all.

Comment: @Can I know why

Comment: You've defined an edge-triggered latch that has three clocks and three inputs. There's no physical circuit that corresponds to this. What are `in1`, `in2` and `d` supposed to be, anyway?

Comment: @DaveTweed Sorry for my ignorance! How does an edge triggered latch differ from a Flipflop

Comment: Can I know why a -ve vote. I know that this code can't be realized by a singe FF, but I was posed with this question which I was not able to answer. So I asked here

Answer (score 2):

If your synthesis library supports it,  a set-reset flip-flop would be generated. Currently there are few issues with the way it is written:

1. output from flip-flops should be assigned by non-blocking `<=` assignment.
2. Async set and reset properties should be constants.

I would suggest:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset or posedge set) begin 
   if(reset)
      out <= 1'b0 ;
   else if(set)
      out <= 1'b1 ;
   else
      out <= d    ;
end
```